# How to fix ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED with Windows 2008 R2 DNS server and Nginx website on Ubuntu server?

Tags: nginx, dns, windows-server-2008-r2, ubuntu-server

I have configured in my DNS server (Windows 2008 R2) with address foo.dev pointing to 10.0.1.50, the ping works fine.

Then I have installed an Ubuntu server at 10.0.1.50 with Nginx default configuration, I've just changed the `server_name` line like this:

```
server_name foo.dev;
error_log /var/log/foo.log debug;
```

Now, when I point to 10.0.1.50 with my browser, I get the **Welcome to nginx!** page and I can see logs, but when I open the url `foo.dev`, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and nothing in the logs.

How can I fix my issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Nginx server listening on port 80?

If not, you would need http://foo.dev:port/